# Django Optimal Way of Getting a List of Model Attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Let's say this is my `models.py` file:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)


class Author(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  papers = models.ManyToManyField(Paper, null=False, blank=False)
```

An author can have multiple papers and a paper can have multiple authors. I need to get all the papers titles for a given author.

In my `views.py`, once I have an author object, I need to get a list with all the titles of his papers. I'm doing this:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
author = Author.objects.get(user=user)
papers = [paper.title for paper in author.papers.all()]
```

Is there a way in Django to make this query without having to iterate over the author papers? Maybe there is a built-in function or something that I'm missing, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough

```
papers_by_author = Author.objects.filter(
    user__username=request.user
    ).values('papers__title')
```

apart from this if you [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in your code. you ll have some speed.

```
 Author.objects.get(user=user).prefetch_related('papers')
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can get all papers of certain author
for example, to get an author like in your code:

```
author = Author.objects.get(user=user)
```

and then to get all the papers of this autor:

```
author.papers.values_list("title", flat=True)
```

the result is a list with title values only.

To sum up, values_list() with flat=True is what You need here!